# Compare a DataFrame to itself? pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with week number as int, item name, and ranking.

For instance:

```
  item_name       ranking  week_number
0      test             4            1
1      test             3            2
```

I'd like to add a new column with the ranking evolution since the last week.

The math is very simple:

```py
df['ranking_evolution'] = ranking_previous_week - df['ranking']
```

It would only require exception handling for week 1.

But I'm not sure how to return the ranking previous week.
I could do it by iterating over the rows but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way so I can just declare a column?

The issue is that I'd have to compare the dataframe to itself.
I've candidly tried:

```py
df['ranking_evolution'] = df['ranking'].loc[(df[item_name] == df['item_name]) & (df['week_number'] == df['week_number'] - 1) - df['ranking']
```

But this return `NaN` values.
Even using a copy returned `NaN` values.

Comment: Is `week_number` sorted, or maybe repeating in cycles? Can the same week number go multiple times before the next week number starts?

Comment: are you looking for `df.ranking.diff()` ?

Comment: @VladimirFokow week_number is not sorted but it can be if needed. The same week number can appear multiple times but only once per item

Comment: repeated how? Like `1-2-3 - 1-2-3 - 1-2-3` or `1-1-1 - 2-2 - 3-3-3` ? or both? then what value should be chosen for the previous week if there are several?

Comment: @Chris it could be but I can't find anything about it, would you mind explaining or do you have a link to share?

Comment: [pd.Series.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)

Comment: oh my bad I'm so used to type my columns as ['column_name'] that I didn't get .ranking is the column. It could be a solution but is there a way to make it work with different item_name on each date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is a simplistic example, you probably have different products and maybe missing weeks?

A robust way would be to perform a self-merge with the week+1:

```
(df.merge(df.assign(week_number=df['week_number']+1),
          on=['item_name', 'week_number'],
          suffixes=(None, '_evolution'),
          how='left')
   .assign(ranking_evolution=lambda d: d['ranking_evolution'].sub(d['ranking']))
 )
```

Output:

```
  item_name  ranking  week_number  ranking_evolution
0      test        4            1                NaN
1      test        3            2                1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, try this code to figure out the trick.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'item_name':   ['test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test'],
    'ranking':     [4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'week_number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['ranking_evolution'] = df['ranking'].diff(-1) # this is the line that does the trick

print(df)
```

Results

```
  item_name  ranking  week_number  ranking_evolution
     test        4            1                1.0
     test        3            2                1.0
     test        2            3                1.0
     test        1            4               -1.0
```